# GCM messages deliver only when app is open

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, react-native

I don't receive GCM push notifications for my Android app when app is closed. However if I send notification and my app is open, the message gets delivered instantly.

The format that I use for GCM:

```
{
    to: 'deviceToken'
    priority: 'high',
    data: {
        id: notification.id,
        message: notification.message,
        path: notification.path
    }
}
```

I am sending silent notifications, I aware that I don't have "notification" field. When I receive silent notification, I send visible local notification. I receive notifications when I debug or when app is running, so there is no reason to think that this workflow doesn't work.

It's a React Native app, I used https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification for push notifications.

Comment: what is a silent notification?

Comment: the notification that is invisible for user, sorry for confusion, it's a concept from iOS.

Comment: are you testing it in emulator or device? if device which model?

Comment: @Zaki both. No issues when app is open, never delivered when it's closed.

Comment: which device model?

Comment: @Zaki Real device - Nexus 5, Emulator - Nexus 5X. Android - at least Marshmallow

Comment: I had same issues, make sure when running it in emulator it is run as "Run" instead of "Debug", this way way when app is killed you will get notifications. Also on device make sure you dont have protected apps in settings if so add your app to protected apps.

Comment: @Zaki I don't see "Protected apps" in my settings.

Comment: which service do you use in android side?

Comment: also check for any power saving options that restrict background messages to apps

Comment: @Zaki it's a react-native app. I used https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: ah sorry thought it was android/java...maybe tag the question as react-native would get you more help. good luck :)

Comment: @Zaki thanks, it's pretty much java, I think something is wrong with the way I use gcm. Thanks for trying anyways.

Comment: You're sending a `data` payload. Try sending a `notification` payload.

Comment: Post your broadcast receiver code

Comment: @AL seems like indeed for some reason notification payload gets delivered unlike data payload. I will research it further and let you know if I get it working.

Comment: Android devices handles the message payload types differently. See the Handling Messages in Android in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, I just needed to remove `id` from data payload and it started working as expected. Maybe it's something internal with the library that I am using or google doesn't like it, not sure.

```
{
    to: 'deviceToken'
    priority: 'high',
    data: {
        message: notification.message,
        path: notification.path
    }
}
```